# binary search tree

Tags: c++

i have implement binary search tree in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class binary{

private:
    struct tree{

        tree *left;
        tree *right;
        int data;
            }; 
    tree *root;
public:
    binary(){

        root=NULL;
            }
    bool empty()  { return root=NULL;}
    void print_inorder();
    void inorder(tree*);
    void print_preorder();
    void pre_order(tree*);
    void print_postorder();
    void post_order(tree *);
    void insert(int);
    void remove(int);


};
void binary::insert(int d){

    tree *t=new tree;
    tree *parent;
    t->data=d;
    t->left=NULL;
    t->right=NULL;
    parent=NULL;
    //is new tree;
      if (empty()) root=t;
      else{

          tree *current;
          current=root;
          //find Nod's parent
          while (current){

              parent=current;
              if (t->data>current->data) current=current->right;
              else current=current->left;
          }
          if (t->data<parent->data)
              parent->left=t;
          else
              parent->right=t;


      }


}
void binary::remove(int d){
    //locate the element
    bool found=true;
     if (empty()){

         cout<<"tree is  empty"<<endl;
          return ;

             }

      tree *current;
      tree *parent;
      current=root;
      while (current!=NULL){
          if (current->data==d){
              found=true;
              break;
          }
          else{
              parent=current;
              if (d>current->data) current=current->right;
              else current=current->left;
          }
      }

      if (!found){
          cout<<"data not found "<<endl;
           return ;
      }


      //three case

      // 1. We're removing a leaf node
    // 2. We're removing a node with a single child
    // 3. we're removing a node with 2 children
      // Node with single child
      if ((current->left==NULL && current->right!=NULL  )||(current->left!=NULL && current->right==NULL)){

          if (current->left==NULL && current->right!=NULL){
              if(parent->left==current){
                  parent->left=current->right;
                  delete current;
              }

              else{
                  parent->right=current->right;
                  delete current;
              }
      }
          else  // left child present, no right child  
          {
              if (parent->left==current){

                  parent->left=current->left;

                  delete current;
                              }


              else{
                  parent->right=current->left;
                  delete current;
              }
      }
                  return ;
}

              if (current->left==NULL   && current->right==NULL){

                  if (parent->left==current) parent->left=NULL;
                  else parent->right==NULL;
                   delete current;
                    return ;

              }

              //node with 2 children
              //replace node with smalles value in right subtree
              if (  current->left!=NULL && current->right!=NULL){

                  tree *ch;
                  ch=current->right;
                  if ((ch->left==NULL) &&(ch->right==NULL))
                  {

                          current=ch;
                          delete ch;
                          current->right=NULL;

                  }

                      else// right child has children
        {
            //if the node's right child has a left child
            // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element
            if ((current->right)->left!=NULL){

                tree * rr;
                tree * lr;
                lr=current->right;
                rr=(current->right)->left;
                while (rr->left!=NULL){

                    lr=rr;
                    rr=rr->left;

                }
                current->data=rr->data;
                delete rr;
                lr->left=NULL;




            }
            else
            {
                 tree *tmp;
                 tmp=current->right;
                 current->data=tmp->data;
                 current->right=tmp->right;
                 delete tmp;

                      }


              }

                       return;
      }



}

              void   binary::print_inorder(){

                  inorder(root);
              }
              void binary::inorder(tree *p){
                  if (p!=NULL){
                      if (p->left) inorder(p->left);
                      cout<<" "<<p->data<<" ";
                      if (p->right) inorder(p->right);
                  }
                  else return ;



                  }


              void binary::print_preorder(){

                  pre_order(root);


              }
              void binary::pre_order(tree *p){

                  if (p!=NULL){
                      cout<<" "<<p->data<<" ";
                      if (p->left) pre_order(p->left);
                      if (p->right) pre_order(p->right);


              }

                  else return ;
              }

              void  binary::print_postorder(){

                  post_order(root);
              }


              void binary::post_order(tree *p){

                  if (p!=NULL){

                      if (p->left) post_order(p->left);
                      if (p->right) post_order(p->right);
                      cout<<"  "<<p->data;
                  }
                  else return ;
              }


int main(){


binary b;
int ch,tmp,tmp1;
while (1){
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" Binary Search Tree Operations "<<endl;
       cout<<" ----------------------------- "<<endl;
       cout<<" 1. Insertion/Creation "<<endl;
       cout<<" 2. In-Order Traversal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 3. Pre-Order Traversal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 4. Post-Order Traversal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 5. Removal "<<endl;
       cout<<" 6. Exit "<<endl;
       cout<<" Enter your choice : ";

       cin>>ch;
       switch(ch)
       {
       case 1:  cout<<"enter number to be inserted:";
           cin>>tmp;
           b.insert(tmp);
           break;
       case 2: cout<<endl;
           cout<<"in order traversal"<<endl;
           cout<<"------------------"<<endl;
           b.print_inorder();
           break;
       case 3:   cout<<endl;
           cout<<"pre order traversal "<<endl;
           cout<<"------------------"<<endl;
           b.print_preorder();
           break;
       case 4: cout<<endl;
           cout<<"post order traversal"<<endl;
           cout<<"---------------------"<<endl;
           b.print_postorder();
           break;
       case 5:  cout<<"enter data to be deleted:";
           cin>>tmp1;
           b.remove(tmp1);
           break;
       case 6:

     return 0;
       }
       }


 return 0;

}
```

it compiles fine    but problem is this it: when i  enter choice  1 it say enter number to be inserted i enter  for example 7 and   program says:

```
binary_tree exe has stopped working  
windows can check online for a solution to the problem
check  online for a solution and close program
close program
```

why?what is reason when such kind of problem occurs?

Comment: This is what stepping through a debugger will help you with, instead of making us bug-fix your code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the code under gdb on a Linux system, this is the reported error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080488ac in binary::insert (this=0xbffff33c, d=7) at so.cpp:52
52            if (t->data<parent->data)
```

In your case, `parent` is NULL; this is becase in your `empty()` method, you're using `root=NULL` (setting `root` to `NULL`) instead of `root==NULL` (checking if `root` is `NULL`).

Comment: davit-datuashvili: always write NULL==root that way the compiler would catch this problem.

Comment: Or use a strongly-typed language that doesn't accept a non-boolean as the return type for a boolean method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
bool empty()  { return root=NULL;}
```

Change to:

```
bool empty()  { return root == NULL;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious error that I see is that your implementation of empty actually deletes the root of your tree.  It should return the result of `root == NULL` rather than the result of the assignment of `NULL` to `root` (`root=NULL`).  Since the tree is actually empty and NULL is equivalent to false, this causes the "search" branch of insert to be taken.  Since `current` (and `root`) is NULL, `parent` never gets set and you get memory access error when you try to check the value of the `parent`'s data.

You likely have other errors, but that's as far as I looked.  I would suggest that you write some unit tests for your individual methods based on specific scenarios to test what happens in each under that scenario's conditions.  It would be better if you wrote the test *before* you wrote just enough code to pass the test so that you knew that when your code passed the test it was correct and covered the test scenario, but you can write them afterwards as well.  It's harder to know that you have exactly the code you need (and no more) if you write them afterwards.   Running these test in the debugger when it fails (spectacularly, in this case) can be helpful to understand what is going wrong, but if you build the code up slowly using your tests as a guide, you can usually pin point where the error is without that.